# allDbs plugin with ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I would like to import and use the allDbs pouchdb plugin in Ionic to list all my database tables. This is what i've done after installed the node module with this command (npm install pouchdb.all-dbs --save):

```
import dbsplugin from 'pouchdb-all-dbs';
console.dir(dbsplugin);



 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
               public http   : HttpClient)
   {  
        dbsplugin.allDbs().then(function (dbs) {

               }).catch(function (err) {
             // handle err
          });
   }
```

[error with allDbs plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGyKU.png)

Answer (score 1):

The thing to understand is that PouchDB is designed as a central core enhanced by plugins.  The plugins cannot be used on their own.  They must be plugged into PouchDB and then used **through** PouchDB.

So, to use the `pouchdb-find` plugin one does:

```
  import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
  import finder from 'pouchdb-find';

  PouchDB.plugin(finder);

  const dbLocal = new PouchDB('myDb');

  dbLocal.find({ selector: { name: 'mario' } })
    .then(rslt) => { /* do stuff */ });
```

In the case of `allDbs`, it makes no sense to run it on a single database, as one has to do for `pouchdb-find`, thus `allDbs` is a class method, not an instance method.

This means, I believe, that you can skip the instantiation and call it directly from Pouch like this:

```
  import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
  import finder from 'pouchdb-find';
  import dbsplugin from 'pouchdb-all-dbs';

  PouchDB.plugin(finder);
  PouchDB.plugin(dbsplugin);

  PouchDB.allDbs().then((dbs) => {
    // dbs is an array of strings, e.g. ['mydb1', 'mydb2']
  }).catch(function (err) {
    // handle err
  });
```

I say "I believe" because I haven't used `pouchdb-all-dbs`.  Nevertheless, give that a try and let me know if it works.